# Как сделать такой <input>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Не подскажете как получить такой input?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да хоть банально `<fieldset>` + `<legend>`, если с CSS не хотите особо играться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Называется input-mask

Примеры:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-input-mask.html

UPD:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <label for="">
    <span>text</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</div>
```

```
label {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-1.5rem);
  left: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px
}
input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Мне нужен вовсе не input-mask. Я бы хотел  узнать как сделать именно рамку как у этого input

Answer (score 0):

Типа такого?

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}

.phone-number {
  border-color: rgb(223, 225, 229);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.phone-number legend {
  color: rgb(106, 106, 106);
  -webkit-text-stroke: rgb(106, 106, 106) 0.2px;
}

.phone-number input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.phone-number [maxlength="3"] {
  margin-right: -8px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="phone-number">
  <legend>Phone Number</legend>
  <span>+7</span>
  <input type="text" maxlength="3" placeholder="---">
  <input type="text" maxlength="3" placeholder="---">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" placeholder="----">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: я бы все же посоветовал использовать maxlength="N"

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato ой да, конечно) Совсем уже забыл...

Comment: Это больше костыль, чем решение

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, а в итоге все равно автору вопроса был нужен не сам ввод, а рамка для ввода. что в целом ответ на вопрос

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Окей, но в любом случае это костыль, потому что нужен инпут с такой рамкой, а не куча инпутов. И по сути всё может быть решено через более простые элементы верстки.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, так действуйте, я вас понял и с первого раза.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Ниже дали ответ уже по сути